# Mover los círculos pintados en canvas con java y android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

Tras una pregunta de @joseba, me puse a curiosear con su código y ahora estoy trabajando en un proyecto para el que no logro tener el resultado satisfactorio

@Joseba preguntaba por la posibilidad de dibujar varias figuras, en mi caso círculo, sin que se borrasen los círculos dibujados con anterioridad. Tras dar con la respuesta, he contetado su pregunta.

Pero ahora biene mi duda, y es la posibilidad de mover cada círculo dibujado.

Llevo infinidad de pruebas y le estoy dedicando mucho más tiempo del que pensaba. Como veréis en el código, tengo muchas filas comentadas de numerosas pruebas que voy realizando, pero ninguna de ellas me funciona.

Ya no pido que me pongáis la solución, me valdría alguna recomendación o enfoque diferente para seguir con las pruebas.

El código que tengo es el siguiente

```
public class ClaseDibujo extends View {

    Paint paint;
    Path path = new Path();

    //String accion = "nada";
    //int puntosHistoricos;

    //Paint p;
    //String txt = "Mueve figura";

    List<Path> paths;
    List<Paint> paints;

    //List<Float> x;
    //List<Float> y;
    //List<Float> r;

    //int circulo = - 1;

    Canvas canvas;

    float Xpush = 300;
    float Ypush = 300;

    //String color = "rojo";
    //String figura = "circulo";
    //String linea = "14";
    float medida = 100;

    public ClaseDibujo(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        paints = new ArrayList<>();

        //x = new ArrayList<Float>();
        //y = new ArrayList<Float>();
        //r = new ArrayList<Float>();

        canvas = new Canvas();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //p = new Paint();
        //p.setAntiAlias(true);
        //p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //p.setTextSize(50);

        //path = new Path();
        //paint = new Paint();

        //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        //paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        //paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        //paint.setColor(Color.RED);


        //if (accion.equals("pulso")){
            //path.moveTo(Xpush, Ypush);

            //paint = new Paint();
            //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            //paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
            //paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            //paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            //canvas.drawCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, paint);

            //paints.add(paint);
            //path = new Path();
            //path.moveTo(Xpush, Ypush);
            //paths.add(path);

            //int i = 0;
            //for (Paint trazo:paints){
            //    canvas.drawCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, paints.get(i++));
            //}
         //}
        //else if (accion.equals("mueve")){
            //path.lineTo(Xpush, Ypush);
            //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            //for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++){
        //    canvas.drawCircle(paths.indexOf(0), paths.indexOf(i), medida, paints.get(i++));
        //}
        //canvas.drawText(txt, 150, 130, p);
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }

    //canvas.drawCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, paint);
    //}


    //int i = 0;
    //for (Paint trazo:paints){
    //    canvas.drawCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, paints.get(i++));
    //}
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //float getX = event.getX();
    //float getY = event.getY();
    //int accion = event.getAction();

    Xpush = event.getX();
    Ypush = event.getY();

    //double cenX = getX - Xpush;
    //double cenY = getY - Ypush;

    //float distancia = (float) Math.sqrt(cenX * cenX + cenY * cenY);

    //x.add(Xpush);
    //y.add(Ypush);
    //r.add(medida);

    //if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //for (int i = 0; i < paints.size(); i++){
                    //double cenX = getX - x.indexOf(i);
                    //double cenY = getY - y.indexOf(i);

                    paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

                    //float distancia = (float) Math.sqrt(cenX * cenX + cenY * cenY);
                    //if (distancia <= r.indexOf(i)){
                        //if (distancia <= medida) {
                            //circulo = i;
                        //if (circulo == i) {
                            //txt = "Moviendo círculo " + i;
                        //}
                        //invalidate();
                    //}
                    //else {
                        paints.add(paint);
                        path = new Path();
                        //path.moveTo(Xpush, Ypush);
                        path.addCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, Path.Direction.CW);
                        paths.add(path);
                    //}
                //}
                //accion = "pulso";


                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //if (circulo > - 1){
                    //x.add() = getX;
                    //y.add() = getY;
                    //invalidate();
                //}
                //break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //accion = "levanta";
                //puntosHistoricos = event.getHistorySize();

                //for (int i = 0; i < puntosHistoricos; i++){
                //    path.lineTo(event.getHistoricalX(i),
                //            event.getHistoricalY(i));
                //}
                //break;
        }

        //switch (event.getAction()){

            //case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                //paint = new Paint();
                //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                //paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
                //paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                //paint.setColor(Color.RED);

                //paint = new Paint();
                //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                //paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
                //paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                //paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                //canvas.drawCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, paint);

                //paints.add(paint);

                //path = new Path();
                //path.moveTo(Xpush, Ypush);
                //paths.add(path);

                //invalidate();

                //break;
            //case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                //break;
            //case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //int puntosHistoricos = event.getHistorySize();
                //for (int i = 0; i < puntosHistoricos; i++){
                    //    path.lineTo(event.getHistoricalX(i),
                    //            event.getHistoricalY(i));
                //}
                //break;
            //default:
                //throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + event.getAction());
        //}
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Sería posible que alguien me ayudara a buscar la solución o me diera la dirección en la que buscar para poder mover los círculos dibujados en el canvas ?

Muchas graciasss

Comment: Me interesa mucho éste tema. Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarte. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

me parece que puedes intentar lo siguiente.

Asumiendo que este view (ClaseDibujo) esta contenido como parte de un activity ( Tambien puede aplicar para fragments )

```
public class CustomViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View customView;
    ....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        customView = findViewbyId(R.id.customView);

        View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            // Agregamos las posiciones de dibujo a tu custom view
            customView.setxPush(motionEvent.getX());
            customView.setYPush(motionEvent.getY());

            // Notificamos que el view vuelva a ejecutar el método onDraw()
            drawBallView.invalidate();

            // Return true significa que el evento se llevo acabo con éxito
            return true;
        }
    };


    customView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    }
}
```

Como dato adicional. Cuando dibujes tu view, recuerda utilizar las variables xPush e yPush para ubicar/ setear la posicion de tu view a la hora de dibujar o cuando se ejecuta el método onDraw() del custom view.

Reference -> https://www.dev2qa.com/android-custom-view-and-ontouchlistener-example-move-view-on-touch-move/